# How does Jest give babel.rc to babel-jest?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs, babel-jest

I just began using babel-plugin-macros in my code, and now all of my Jest tests are failing. I have a somewhat complex monorepo setup - when I tried reducing it to a super-simple example, I could not reproduce the test, so it probably has something to do with my directory structure.

I looked at the source code of babel-jest etc. If I manually force the plugin to be picked up, by adding this around line 187 of babel-jest/build/index.js

```
const transformResult = (0, (_babelCore || _load_babelCore()).transform)(src,
   { ...theseOptions, plugins: ['macros'] }
);
```

Everything works perfectly. So the problem is that it does not pick up the `plugins: ['macros']` from my .babelrc. I looked at the function `getBabelRC`, and by console.logging, I seem to confirm that the correct .babelrc (with plugin: macros) is loaded etc. However, no matter how long I look at the code, I cannot figure out how the .babelrc loaded in `getBabelRC` is supposed to make it down to the `process` function. If I console.log `theseOptions`, none of my custom settings are there.

I'm happy to debug this myself, but if anyone could help me understand a bit the flow of data, that would be incredibly helpful!

To reproduce, check out https://github.com/chili-epfl/FROG, switch to branch `automaticimport`, run `./initial_setup.sh`, and then `npm start jest`.

Comment: I couldn't find any `automaticimport` branch.

Comment: In the `master` I see a `babel.config.js` file but no `.babelrc`.

Comment: Could you elaborate the lines of .babelrc where you include the plugin?